# How to update UI in real-time from service?

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer, media-player, audio-streaming

I know, that for correct architecture of media player app we need to use service for player logic. So how i can update UI from service in real-time for my FRAGMENTS? I need to bind service to host activity and...? Or not? Help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RxJava or EventBus to send your data to fragment and then in fragment update ui.

be careful in fragment you must use **runOnUiThread**.